# need to divide circle image to 8 part, and put label on each part. pressing label will turn the circle to the divided part

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a circle image (like a roulette template), and I need to split it to 8, and put label on each part. when pressing on divided part, I need the circle will point on the correct part.

this is jsfiddle of what I have in a mean time:
http://jsfiddle.net/EYALIN/x8q9nqt1/

this is JS:

```
var img = document.querySelector('img');
img.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);


function onClick() {
    this.removeAttribute('style');

    var deg = 500 + Math.round(Math.random() * 500);

    var css = '-webkit-transform: rotate(' + deg + 'deg);';

    this.setAttribute(
        'style', css
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is create this image in photoshop with the dividers and then use image map to select those dividers, then use jQuery to select them. I will post an image and image map code soon.

[image: This is an example image, you need to create it to your likings]

Then we use an [image map generator](http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de/)

And get this result:

```
<img src="url/to/your/image.jpg" alt="" usemap="#Map" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="rect" coords="506,493,510,1017" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="901,833,519,496,518,503,895,839" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="499,499,139,848,132,842,495,493" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="492,495,12,502,13,491,493,488" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="152,174,500,478,492,484,146,183" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="498,21,502,473,512,474,507,20" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="853,156,515,479,522,484,859,163" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="1005,484,526,487,528,496,1003,494" />
</map>
```

Now you can use jQuery to select the different dividers and hook events to them:

```
$('area').each(function() {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: the problem is also that i need to change class of all divided part each time i touch it. like highlight it or something like it

Comment: simple jQuery... use `toggleClass` function for that. http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: when i edit it in jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/x8q9nqt1/1/) it is not goes to your function. can yopu please take a look and what's wrong ?

Comment: Few things: 1. You forgot to load jQuery. 2. The code was incorrect, I revised my answer. 3. I uploaded the circle with the dividers. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x8q9nqt1/2/

Comment: i need to use my picture because there is an arrow there. when i press on a divided part, i need that the arrow will point on it and gave it blue color. anyway i appreciate  your help

Comment: Use two pictures, one would be the one I created and on top of that place your arrow. Hook event, `on('click'` to your arrow and use your random rotation function **ONLY** when a divider is clicked. If this answer satisfies you, please accept it and vote up. Thanks